# Shopify API fulfilment update fails unprocessable entity

Tags: php, json, api, shopify

I developed a web application that uses the Shopify API a while back, it's been running without a problem for about 2 months now, until this week when an error started to occur.

We are trying to update an orders fulfilment using an API call in PHP.

In PHP we POST to the following:
http://www.the-web-shop-like-this.com/admin/orders/0123456789/fulfillments.json

We POST the following variable: $fulfillment_update

The variable is set like so:

```
$fulfillment_update = "
     'fulfillment': { 
        'tracking_number': '',
        'notify_customer': true
            }";
```

POST'ing the blank tracking_number was to force the shopify system into generating the fulfilment email and for marking that order as fulfilled - no tracking number is ever added and notify_customer is always set to true.

Shopify API comes back (since the weekend) saying: 'Unprocessable Entity'.

Any ideas Ladies & Gents?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the behavior with having an empty 'tracking_number' to invoke some specific behavior documented or is that a hack on your own? Maybe they just fixed a bug you relied on…

Comment: I was mimicking the way in which you could use the back-end admin panel built into Shopify in that you could just click 'update fulfilment information' and leave the tracking number blank.

You could be right in saying they've fixed a bug - The only problem is for people who don't wish to send out tracking information - I have contacted Shopify but they usually take many days to respond.

Fingers crossed there is a way around it!

Comment: instead of mimicking something, you should read the API documentation…

Comment: If it helps: http://api.shopify.com/fulfillment.html - "Modify an existing Fulfillment" -> There is no mention of whether or not either of the variables are required or must be posted/put to do the job ? Does this signify a lack of proper documentation?

Comment: Well, in their example they set `tracking_number` to `NULL` not to an empty string as you have done. Have you tried that?

Comment: Have also tried NULL, null, 'null', 'NULL'.
Can't find a break-down of why 'Unprocessable Entity' would be returned.. documentation lacks a little imo

Comment: The URL you've specified is lacking a fulfillment id, which is required if you're trying to update a specific fulfillment. That's all I can tell you without the actual shop name and API key you're using.

Comment: @DavidUnderwood - Shop: iphone-surgery.myshopify.com API KEY: 8bef90e666ae1ce23f0163834b1b3c47

Your documentation says I can fulfill all order lines using the code exactly as above - thanks for getting in touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing some strange param encoding on your request params. Here's what Rails is getting:

```
{"_json"=>"'fulfillment': { 'tracking_number': '', 'notify_customer': true}", "order_id"=>"147265452"}
```

This is a hash with a key `'_json'` and a value containing the json as a string. This suggests that you're passing your data incorrectly somehow. Can you post the full code you're using to kick off the HTTP request?

P.S.: Are you aware of the existing client libraries for PHP? Here's a list, I highly recommend using one of them unless you have a specific reason not to: http://wiki.shopify.com/Shopify_App_Development#.E2.80.9CI.E2.80.99m_a_PHP_developer.E2.80.9D

Comment: Just to clarify for me:
I was under the impression that "http://www.the-web-shop-like-this.com/admin/orders/0123456789/fulfillments/12345.json" was to be used for updating an existing fulfillment only?

Perhaps along the way I have confused you - We just want to set an order to fulfilled no matter what lines are on it - are you saying that we can no longer set an entire order to 'fulfilled' ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your wording in the question ("We are trying to **update** an orders fulfilment") confused me. I'll edit my answer to match your actual problem :)

Comment: Rather than waste too much time of your time I am now suspicious that there may be non UTF8 characters in my code (no idea where they've come from) and will let you know once I've pursued this avenue of investigation!

Comment: Doesn't matter what I do Shopify just returns "Not Found" when using PUT, if I use POST i get the unprocessable entity error come back

Comment: Thanks for your help David - your answer pointed me in the right direction - i think there was two issues:
1) I wasn't sending my parameters through to the PHP 'call' function as an array properly - so it was sending them through to Shopify wrong.

2) There was (i believe) some strange ANSI characters in the file - I've re-encoded the files to UTF8